# Splitting a String URL into words Using Python

Tags: python, url, split

How can I get various words from a string(URL) in python?
From a URL like:

```
http://www.sample.com/level1/level2/index.html?id=1234
```

I want to get words like:

```
http, www, sample, com, level1, level2, index, html, id, 1234
```

Any solutions using python.

Thanks.

Comment: And i want to store the result in a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you may do it for all URL

```
import re
def getWordsFromURL(url):
    return re.compile(r'[\:/?=\-&]+',re.UNICODE).split(url)
```

Now you may use it as

```
url = "http://www.sample.com/level1/level2/index.html?id=1234"
words = getWordsFromURL(url)
```

Comment: I thought you wanted `['http', 'www', 'sample', 'com', 'level1', 'level2', 'index', 'html', 'id', '1234']`, not `['http', 'www.sample.com', 'level1', 'level2', 'index.html?id', '1234']`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i have compiled as re.UNICODE now it works for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935748/splitting-a-stri‌​ng-url-into-words-us‌​ing-python

Answer (score 2):

just regex-split according to the biggest sequence of non-alphanums:

```
import re
l = re.split(r"\W+","http://www.sample.com/level1/level2/index.html?id=1234")
print(l)
```

yields:

```
['http', 'www', 'sample', 'com', 'level1', 'level2', 'index', 'html', 'id', '1234']
```

This is simple but as someone noted, doesn't work when there are `_`, `-`, ... in URL names. So the less fun solution would be to list all possible tokens that can separate path parts:

```
l = re.split(r"[/:\.?=&]+","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935748/splitting-a-stri‌​ng-url-into-words-us‌​ing-python")
```

(I admit that I may have forgotten some separation symbols)

Comment: Doesn't work with URLs like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935748/splitting-a-string-url-into-words-using-python`

Comment: @Himal check my answer,it covers that

Comment: no it doesn't: `['http', 'www.sample.com', 'level1', 'level2', 'index.html?id', '1234']`

Comment: It Worked for me... Thanks :-)